# identify Image composition element in a picture(Rule of third or Framing)

Tags: matlab

How to use ROI to find out the location of the object in a photo, because i need to classify the image composition of a photo, either it is Rule Of Third or Framing.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to ask a more precise question.

Comment: I need to classify the type of photo, such as, if the photo is use Rule of third technique or framing technique.
So I need to detect the location of the subject in the photo.
Any suggestion?